# Join collection in QueryOver with projections

Tags: c#, nhibernate, outer-join, queryover, nhibernate-projections

I want to retrieve the list of short `User` versions with their `Characters` collection (short version too). I use QueryOver with projections.

```
public class User
{
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Nickname { get; set; }
        public virtual ISet<Character> Characters { get; set; }
        // and 30 other properties
}

public class Character
{
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int XP { get; set; }
        public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual int ClassId { get; set; }
        // and 30 other properties
}

public class UserDto // short version
{
        public virtual string Nickname { get; set; }
        public virtual ISet<CharacterDto> Characters { get; set; }
}


public class CharacterDto // short version
{
        public virtual int XP { get; set; }
        public virtual int ClassId { get; set; }
}

    User userAlias = null;
    UserDto userDto = null;
    Character characterAlias = null;
    CharacterDto characterDto = null;

    var result = session.QueryOver<User>(() => userAlias)
            .Where(Restrictions.Like(
                Projections.SqlFunction("lower", NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property<User>(x => x.Nickname)),
                nickname.ToLowerInvariant(), MatchMode.Start))
            .JoinAlias(x => x.Characters, () => characterAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
             .Select(
                 Projections.Property(() => userAlias.Nickname).WithAlias(() => userDto.Nickname),
                 Projections.Property(() => userAlias.Characters).WithAlias(() => userDto.Characters),
                 Projections.Property(() => characterAlias.XP).WithAlias(() => characterDto.XP),
                 Projections.Property(() => characterAlias.ClassId).WithAlias(() => characterDto.ClassId)
                )
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<UserDto>())
             .Take(50)
             .List<UserDto>();
```

When I run this code it throws an exception: `Could not find a setter for property ClassId in class UserDto`. If I remove the transformer then the result contains entries for one character per each user (User1-Character1, User1-Character2, ...). Each entry has correct nickname and character class id but wrong xp (user id instead) and characters collection (== null).

How can I get the correct data without using hql or doing seperate queries for characters?

**update**

I removed the transformer and commented out `Projections.Property(() => userAlias.Characters)...`, now it returns the correct results but is there a way to transform them into projected dtos like AliasToBeanTransformer does and collapse the repeated user data for each character entries?

Comment: You are trying to project to two different object types (`UserDto` and `CharacterDto`). I don't think it's supported. If you look at your code, you tell NHibernate that he should use `UseDto` (`Transformers.AliasToBean<UserDto>()`) but you don't tell it about `CharacterDto`.

Comment: Ok, so what's the correct way to do that? Also see the part about that it doesn't return correct `xp` values but uses `user_id`s insteads.

Comment: Normally this `Projections.SqlFunction("lower", ` should be useless, because columns in SQL Server by default are case insensitive.

Comment: @xanatos I use postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to project to two different object types (`UserDto` and `CharacterDto`). I don't think it's supported. If you look at your code, you tell NHibernate that he should use `UseDto` (`Transformers.AliasToBean<UserDto>()`) but you don't tell it about `CharacterDto`.

See for example http://blog.andrewawhitaker.com/blog/2014/06/19/queryover-series-part-4-transforming/ :

> You cannot populate collections (e.g., if you had a class with ProductID and a collection of ProductReviews you could not do that in one step using AliasToBean)

What you can do:

Add a class with everything (`UserCharacterDto`)

```
public class UserCharacterDto // short version
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Nickname { get; set; }
    public virtual int? XP { get; set; }
    public virtual int? ClassId { get; set; }
}

public class UserDto // short version
{
    public virtual string Nickname { get; set; }
    // Changed from ISet: you don't have a key!
    public virtual IList<CharacterDto> Characters { get; set; }
}

public class CharacterDto // short version
{
    public virtual int XP { get; set; }
    public virtual int ClassId { get; set; }
}
```

and first you project to `UserCharacterDto`,

```
UserCharacterDto uc = null;

IList<UserCharacterDto> result = ...

    .Select(
        Projections.Property(() => userAlias.Nickname).WithAlias(() => uc.Nickname),
        Projections.Property(() => characterAlias.XP).WithAlias(() => uc.XP),
        Projections.Property(() => characterAlias.ClassId).WithAlias(() => uc.ClassId)
    )
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<UserDto>())
    .Take(50)
    .List<UserCharacterDto>()
```

then you `GroupBy` and in the end you create your elements

```
IList<UserDto> result2 = (from x in result
                          // Here you group by User
                          group x by x.Id into y
                          let first = y.First()
                          // Here you build the "definitive" UserDto
                          select new UserDto {
                              Nickname = first.Nickname,
                              // and here you build the "definitive" CharacterDto
                              // note the handling of empty objects!
                              Characters = new List<CharacterDto>(y.Select(z => z.XP != null && z.ClassId != null ? new CharacterDto { XP = z.XP.Value, ClassId = z.ClassId.Value } : null))
                          }
                         ).ToList();

// remove empty CharacterDto from left join
foreach (UserDto user in result2) {
    if (user.Characters.Count == 1 && user.Characters[0] == null) {
        user.Characters.Clear();
    }
}
```

(note that I'm not using the functional syntax of LINQ because I want to use the `let` keyword)

Comment: ClassId and XP are not nullable. When there are no characters the db returns null for these fields and AliasToBeanTransformer would throw an exception, yes? How can I handle it manually? Can I make these fields nullable only for the short dto version?

Comment: @Vlad No, I've done some changes and now it should work

Comment: thanks, interesting that I've just checked (only nh without grouping part) and the previous version without `int?` works ok when there are no characters

Comment: `.Take(50)` returns 50 *combined* results (with duplicated users) but not 50 users. Is it possible to limit the number of users to be returned?

Comment: @Vlad I was thinking the same thing when I was going home... I hoped you wouldn't notice/wouldn't care :-) No, it's very very difficult/nearly impossible to solve this problem. At this point you normally begin writing directly SQL and/or writing an SQL View and using ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: @Vlad There is another solution, but it's quite complex and the code is totally different from the one I wrote here: you do two queries: one for the User with the Take(50) and one for the Character with a IsIn(...) with the IDs taken from the query of the User. You can do it in two ways: the "easy way" is that you execute the User query, then take the IDs, then execute the Character query, then merge the two result sets, the other (more difficult) is that you do the two queries in the same batch. The User query with the Top50 and the Character query with a subquery identical to the User query